# Prime OS Doesn't Seem To Boot Up Correctly

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, android-x86

I just installed Prime OS on a virtual machine to try it out. I just downloaded the `.iso` and added it to the disk drive of the virtual machine, and ran the installer.

After installation, it boots up to a terminal screen like the following:

```
PrimeOS x86_64:/ #
```

I tried seeing what commands there were, so I typed help, but it said to use the toybox command to see a list of all commands. I did that, and none of them seemed to be anything that would help me.

I also looked up to see if anyone else has had this issue, but I didn't find anything that went over possible issues after installation.

What should I do to fix this?

**EDIT:** I just watched a video of someone installing it, and their boot goes to that terminal page for a tiny bit and then loads the OS, but for some reason mine just sits at that page forever, and doesn't change.

Comment: Pleas edit your question to add details on how you installed Prime OS. Maybe a link to a tutorial?

Comment: I just added some info, I didn't follow a tutorial... I just downloaded the `.iso` file and ran the installer from the VM, and it all went smoothly until I booted up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed some settings of the Virtual Machine, and now it booted past the terminal page. I had the virtual machine type at Linux, and I changed it to "Other" and "Other/Unkown (64-bit)" for the version.